# Regular Expression Help - Split on "/" where not in brackets

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, split

I'm trying to split a string using regular expressions. I want to split the string at every "/" symbol, unless that "/" is inside brackets. So for example, the input value:

```
test1 / test2 (test2/test3) / test 4
```

...would give me the array:

```
test1
test2 (test2/test3)
test 4
```

I've seen a few similar queries, but because of the symbols involved, I'm struggling with the syntax. Is it even possible with regEx? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/(?![^(]*\))
```

You can split by this to get the desired result.The `lookahead` will make sure the `/` is not in brackets

```
string strRegex = @"/(?![^(]*\))";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
string strTargetString = @"test1 / test2 (test2/test3) / test 4" + "\n";

return myRegex.Split(strTargetString);
```

Comment: this doesn't work with `test1 / test2 (test2/(test5)test3) / test 4`

Comment: @fubo if its nested parenthesis then it wont work as it would need recursive regex but OP didnt mention that

Comment: it should probably be `[^\(]` instead of `[^(]`

Comment: @tafia inside `[]` `(` has no special meaning